How to change the oil life **interval** in a 2012 Chevy Equinox
When I bought the car I realized the “remaining oil life” percent would be getting close to 10% around the 3,000 mile mark. However, on my last two oil changes it was still way above 40%. Which would put it in the 5-6000 mile range which is not what I want it to be at. Does anyone know if it is possible to change this number back to ~3000? For clarification I am not trying to set the percent display back to 100%. I am trying to change the interval at which it reaches 0% since it is currently way too high.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

What does your vehicle manual say is the expected range?

If you want to spend money on oil-related maintenance, spend it on used oil analysis, which will scientifically tell you that the oil life indicator is fine.

No, it is set where it's at.
It doesn't base it on mileage alone. They put an algorithm in there to estimate when the oil is through. This is based off of mileage, how the vehicle is used, and other factors. If you're using the proper oil (ie: not only weight, but Dexos rating, too), you can run it until it gets down to zero without detriment to your engine. The oil will continue to provide protection for your engine while the oil life meter is showing good. Obviously, you can change out your oil whenever you want, but for the most part, the old 3000 mile oil change is a thing of the past and you're just wasting money. I will say, however: your car; your money; do as you will.

For GM vehicles, it's based on a combo of cumulative engine revs, a mileage cap, and a time limit, as per this SB.  Given that engine wear is more or less proportional to how many revs the engine experiences, I'd trust the oil life algorithm over some fixed mileage.  (ofc, if you want to know for sure, do what the big boys do and send a sample out for lab analysis)
